# How to add two certain date limits on start date and enf date in any date range picker in react

Tags: reactjs

I need to use a date range picker in which I need to implement the logic

Start date can be upto 6 months from today well end date will can be up to 6 months from a start date in a single date range selector

Well I played with different packages but I can able to set a limit on any one date.

Suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Have you checked out moment.js? They have an add and a substract function, where you manipulate dates. For example now plus six months would be:
    moment().add(6, "months")

Check it out at https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Comment: What is the question here? How to get the start and end dates of a 6 month date range? Or you want suggestions on date range pickers for React?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-calendar with moment, it supports some props two of which are minDate and maxDate.

Render two instances of react-calendar, pass `minDate={moment().subtract(6, 'months')}` and `maxDate={moment()}`.

Disable the second instance by default or render it only when user select a date in the first instance of the calendar.
Then pass `minDate={dateSelectedInFirstInstance.add(1, 'day')}` and `maxDate={dateSelectedInFirstInstance.add(6, 'month')}`.